# Recompile block modified by external scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have to use a framework that modifies my DOM. Here is some example HTML that gets used:

```
<div id="testID" ng-show="example === 'show'">Some Content</div>
```

wil be modified by the Framework to something like this:

```
<div id="wrapperOne">
    <div id="wrapperTwo">
        <div id="testID" ng-show="example === 'show'">Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This gets done by calling a JS function like this one:

```
framework.wrap($("#testID"));
```

As you see, the framework wraps the old HTML with some other elements.
My problem is, that Angular does not show the div, when $scope.example becomes 'show'. Without using the framework, it works fine, I think the problem is, that angular compiles the DOM before the framework changes it. The framework has to wait for an ajax request, so just including the angular scripts after it does not work.

I am searching for a solution to force angular to "recompile" the whole DOM, better some parts of it.
Is this the right proposal, or is there any other way to do this? Just omitting the framework isn't the solution as I have to use it.

Thank you very much,

-Lukas

Comment: not likely to get much help without providing more code showing how you use framework within your app

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with `ng-transclude`

I've created a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zghuoxhb/2/

**directive:**

```
.directive('myWrapper', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "my-wrapper-template.html",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: false
    };
})
```

**html:**

```
<my-wrapper>
    <div id="testID" ng-show="example === 'show'">Some Content</div>
</my-wrapper>
```

**output:**
[image]

**BTW excellent question, this is a good use case to showcase the awesomeness of angular**

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds very good. The only problem is, that the wrapper divs are generated by the mentioned framework, so adding the ng-transclude tag to them would be very dirty as I had to insert it with some javascript after the div generation. Is there a way without this ng-transclude tag in the wrapper divs?

Comment: @LukasKolletzki: please create a jsfiddle with your situation

Comment: Ok, I solved this problem, told the creater of the framework to implement the ng-transclude tag. Thank you very much!